# Regression on data series with different intervals

Tags: regression, time-series, data-transformation

I want to do a linear regression on a variable y that depends on several variables x1,x2,x3 that I think is important.

However, x1 has readings everyday, x2 only has readings on weekdays, and x3 only has readings every half year. On the other hand, y has readings every weekdays.

How can I treat these data in order to do a meaningful regression ?

Comment: x2 not having readings on weekends. Does it mean something on its own? Does assuming Friday's value to be constant on saturday and sunday violate any domain requirements?

Comment: Well, to be specific, x1 is Forex rate, x2 is the market index, and x3 is a financial metric of a company which is only reported every 1/2 year.

    So, it can be assumed x2 is constant on Sat and Sun, but x3 should not be assumed constant throughout each data point as the company is doing business continuously and the market is re-valuating the company based on the recent news.